# Каким образом объявляется переменная-вектор-структура?(Си)

Tags: c, переменные, структуры, вектор

Вообщем есть структура "Дети" , в ней содержится имя и дата рождения. Каким образом считать вектор из n детей , как объявить переменную-вектор.
Так?

```
struct Dety v[];
```

или как?

Comment: `struct Dety v[n];`

Answer (score 2):

Так и объявляется

```
struct Dety v[n];
```

Правда это принято назвать *массивом*.

А уж как вы будете его считывать зависит от массы деталей, которые вы в своем вопросе не привели.